# VSTO; date text direction changes after replace

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I'm trying to put Persian date which has right to left direction instead of a text [Date] in a word file using VSTO. but when the replacement code runs the text copied in the word file has a left to right direction.

My code to do so is like this:

```
    Object oMissing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Object oTemplatePath = AssemblyDirectory + "\\ReceiptTemplate.docx";
                try
                {
                    wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref oTemplatePath, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing);
                    var sel = wordApp.Selection;
sel.Find.Text = "[Date]";
                sel.Find.Replacement.Text = PersianCharacterConverter.ToPersianNumber(chequeInfo.ChequeDate);
                sel.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                sel.Find.Forward = true;
                sel.Find.Format = false;
                sel.Find.MatchCase = false;
                sel.Find.MatchWholeWord = false;
                sel.Find.Execute(Replace: WdReplace.wdReplaceAll);
wordDoc.PrintOut();
                //wordDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(chequeInfo.Path+"\\" + chequeInfo.ChequeNumber + ".pdf", WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF);
                object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                wordDoc.Close(false);
                if (wordDoc != null)
                    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wordDoc);
                wordDoc = null;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var my = ex.Message;
                throw;
            }
```

When debugging as you see in the image the value has correct direction
[image: The date direction is correct]

But when it gets replaced in Ms Word the date changes to:

```
۰۲/۰۲/۱۳۹۵
```

While I need this:

۱۳۹۵/۰۲/۰۲

And also this is my PersianCharacterConverter:

```
public static class PersianCharacterConverter
    {

        private static readonly string[] pn = { "۰", "۱", "۲", "۳", "۴", "۵", "۶", "۷", "۸", "۹" };
        private static readonly string[] en = { "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9" };
        public static string ToPersianNumber(string strNum)
        {
            string chash = strNum;
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                chash = chash.Replace(en[i], pn[i]);
            return chash;
        }
        public static string ToPersianNumber(int intNum)
        {
            string chash = intNum.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                chash = chash.Replace(en[i], pn[i]);
            return chash;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The value you are parsing is in different `datetime`, you need to parse the date and convert it `Persian Calendar` then Convert it `ToPersianNumber`.

here is the persian calendar method i've found by search:

```
string GregorianDate = "Thursday, October 24, 2013";
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse(GregorianDate);
PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", pc.GetYear(d), pc.GetMonth(d), pc.GetDayOfMonth(d)));
```

Comment: Before using PersianCharacterConverter.ToPersianNumber method everything is correct but when I use this method the direction get changed

Comment: @AminMohammadi your ToPersianNumber Method looks fine to me are you sure you have the problem within this method?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a trick to solve the problem:

```
private string ConvertToPersianDateFormat(string date)
        {
            String[] items = date.Split('/');
            string temp = "";
            temp = items[0];
            items[0] = items[2];
            items[2] = temp;
            return items[0]+"/"+items[1]+"/"+items[2];
        }
```

Using this method when I call:

```
PersianCharacterConverter.ToPersianNumber(chequeInfo.ChequeDate);
```

I wrap it with ConvertToPersianDateFormat method:

```
ConvertToPersianDateFormat(PersianCharacterConverter.ToPersianNumber(chequeInfo.ChequeDate));
```

So it changes year and day place